# Recommendation how to select aerobic trainer for home

Tags: exercise, workout, cardio, training, health-risk

I am considering buying ab aerobic trainer for my home because I have relatively high cholesterol. But I have two constraints:

- I have a relatively small space with dimensions 1m x 2m.
- I'd like it to be relatively cheap.

Would this kind of equipment:

http://en.everfit.it/products/mini-steppers/step-up/

help lower my cholesterol?

Another option is a stationary bike - but they occupy larger space and are relatively more expensive.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Is equipment a requirement? There's an awful lot you can do in a small space w/ zero equipment required. I'd start there. I'm not personally a big fan of mini-steppers--never saw the point when there are so many other options. But they're cheap :shrug:

Comment: As @DaveNewton said, you don't need to spend a lot of money to get an aerobic workout.  If you have stairs where you live, you can do a step workout.